# Websocket client message payload "does not live long enough"

Tags: rust

I modified an [existing websocket client](https://github.com/cyderize/rust-websocket) to save the message payload from the websocket server:

```
fn main()
{
    let mut globaltest = "";

    // ...some othercode


    let receive_loop = thread::spawn(move || {
        // Receive loop
        for message in receiver.incoming_messages() {
            let message: Message = match message {
                Ok(m) => m,
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Receive Loop: {:?}", e);
                    let _ = tx_1.send(Message::close());
                    return;
                }
            };
            match message.opcode {
                Type::Close => {
                    // Got a close message, so send a close message and return
                    let _ = tx_1.send(Message::close());
                    return;
                }
                Type::Ping => match tx_1.send(Message::pong(message.payload)) {
                    // Send a pong in response
                    Ok(()) => (),
                    Err(e) => {
                        println!("Receive Loop: {:?}", e);
                        return;
                    }
                },
                // Say what we received
                _ => {
                    println!("Receive Loop: {:?}", message);
                        // recive from motion
                        let buf = &message.payload;
                        {
                            let s = match str::from_utf8(buf) {
                                Ok(v) => v,
                                Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
                            };
                            println!("{}",s);

                            ////>>> problem here <<<
                            globaltest = s;
                        }

                    },
            }
        }
    });


    // ...some othercode

}
```

When I build, I get an error message:

```
nathaniel@nathaniel-virtual-machine:~/rustcoderep/rsdummywsclient$ sudo cargo build
   Compiling rsdummywsclient v0.1.0 (file:///home/nathaniel/rustcoderep/rsdummywsclient)
src/main.rs:94:36: 94:51 error: `message.payload` does not live long enough
src/main.rs:94                         let buf = &message.payload;
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: reference must be valid for the static lifetime...
src/main.rs:75:6: 106:4 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 75:5
src/main.rs:75          };
src/main.rs:76          match message.opcode {
src/main.rs:77              Type::Close => {
src/main.rs:78                  // Got a close message, so send a close message and return
src/main.rs:79                  let _ = tx_1.send(Message::close());
src/main.rs:80                  return;
               ...
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I have no idea why. I tried a lot of solutions like `Arc` and `Mutex`, but none of them work :(

When I remove `globaltest = s`, the code builds and runs without problems. So I tried to write a simpler example:

```
use std::str;
use std::thread;

fn main() {

    let mut y = 2;

    let receive_loop = thread::spawn(move || {
         let x = 1;

         y = x;
          println!("tt{:?}",y);
    });

    let receive_loop2 = thread::spawn(move || {

          println!("tt2{:?}",y);
    });

  println!("{:?}",y);

}
```

This works... with almost the same structure.

Here is the full code, only a little different from the rust-websocket client sample:

```
extern crate websocket;

fn main() {
    use std::thread;
    use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
    use std::io::stdin;
    use std::str;
    use websocket::{Message, Sender, Receiver};
    use websocket::message::Type;
    use websocket::client::request::Url;
    use websocket::Client;

    let mut globaltest ="";

    let url = Url::parse("ws://127.0.0.1:2794").unwrap();

    println!("Connecting to {}", url);

    let request = Client::connect(url).unwrap();

    let response = request.send().unwrap(); // Send the request and retrieve a response

    println!("Validating response...");

    response.validate().unwrap(); // Validate the response

    println!("Successfully connected");

    let (mut sender, mut receiver) = response.begin().split();

    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    let tx_1 = tx.clone();

    let send_loop = thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            // Send loop
            let message: Message = match rx.recv() {
                Ok(m) => m,
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Send Loop: {:?}", e);
                    return;
                }
            };
            match message.opcode {
                Type::Close => {
                    let _ = sender.send_message(&message);
                    // If it's a close message, just send it and then return.
                    return;
                },
                _ => (),
            }
            // Send the message
            match sender.send_message(&message) {
                Ok(()) => (),
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Send Loop: {:?}", e);
                    let _ = sender.send_message(&Message::close());
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    let receive_loop = thread::spawn(move || {
        // Receive loop
        for message in receiver.incoming_messages() {
            let message: Message = match message {
                Ok(m) => m,
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Receive Loop: {:?}", e);
                    let _ = tx_1.send(Message::close());
                    return;
                }
            };
            match message.opcode {
                Type::Close => {
                    // Got a close message, so send a close message and return
                    let _ = tx_1.send(Message::close());
                    return;
                }
                Type::Ping => match tx_1.send(Message::pong(message.payload)) {
                    // Send a pong in response
                    Ok(()) => (),
                    Err(e) => {
                        println!("Receive Loop: {:?}", e);
                        return;
                    }
                },
                // Say what we received
                _ => {
                    println!("Receive Loop: {:?}", message);
                        // recive from motion
                        let buf = &message.payload;
                        {
                            let s = match str::from_utf8(buf) {
                                Ok(v) => v,
                                Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
                            };
                            println!("{}",s);
                            globaltest = s;
                        }

                    },
            }
        }
    });

    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();

        stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

        let trimmed = input.trim();

        let message = match trimmed {
            "/close" => {
                // Close the connection
                let _ = tx.send(Message::close());
                break;
            }
            // Send a ping
            "/ping" => Message::ping(b"PING".to_vec()),
            // Otherwise, just send text
            _ => Message::text(trimmed.to_string()),
        };

        match tx.send(message) {
            Ok(()) => (),
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Main Loop: {:?}", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // We're exiting

    println!("Waiting for child threads to exit");

    let _ = send_loop.join();
    let _ = receive_loop.join();

    println!("Exited");
}
```

---

@fjh thanks your reply!

I modified my code into this, changing `globaltest` in `receive_loop` and accessing it from the main thread loop. I still get a confusing error, even after spending three hours I still cannot solve it :(

```
fn main() {

    let mut globaltest:Arc<Mutex<String>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::from("")));

    //some other code...

    let receive_loop = thread::spawn(move || {

        // Receive loop
        for message in receiver.incoming_messages() {
            let message: Message = match message {
                Ok(m) => m,
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Receive Loop: {:?}", e);
                    let _ = tx_1.send(Message::close());
                    return;
                }
            };
            match message.opcode {
                Type::Close => {
                    // Got a close message, so send a close message and return
                    let _ = tx_1.send(Message::close());
                    return;
                }
                Type::Ping => match tx_1.send(Message::pong(message.payload)) {
                    // Send a pong in response
                    Ok(()) => (),
                    Err(e) => {
                        println!("Receive Loop: {:?}", e);
                        return;
                    }
                },
                // Say what we received
                _ => { 
                        let mut globaltest_child = globaltest.lock().unwrap();

                        println!("Receive Loop: {:?}", message);
                        // recive from motion
                        let buf = &message.payload;
                        {
                            let s = match str::from_utf8(buf) {
                                Ok(v) => v,
                                Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
                            };

                            {
                                //>>> if I do like this, globaltest value will same like globaltest_child??
                                *globaltest_child = String::from(s); 
                                println!("{:?}",globaltest_child.clone()); 
                            }
                        } 
                    },
            }
        }
    });

    loop { 
        let message = Message::text("mtconnect");

        match tx.send(message) {
            Ok(()) => (),
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Main Loop: {:?}", e);
                break;
            }
        }

        ///>>> problem here////
        println!("{:?}",globaltest.clone()); 
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(3000)); 
    } 
}
```

The compiler always tells me:

```
athaniel@nathaniel-virtual-machine:~/rustcoderep/rsadapter$ sudo cargo run
   Compiling rsadapter v0.1.0 (file:///home/nathaniel/rustcoderep/rsadapter)
src/main.rs:166:25: 166:35 error: use of moved value: `globaltest` [E0382]
src/main.rs:166         println!("{:?}",globaltest.clone()); 
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:2:25: 2:56 note: in this expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: in this expansion of print! (defined in <std macros>)
src/main.rs:166:9: 166:45 note: in this expansion of println! (defined in <std macros>)
src/main.rs:166:25: 166:35 help: run `rustc --explain E0382` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:102:35: 153:3 note: `globaltest` moved into closure environment here because it has type `alloc::arc::Arc<std::sync::mutex::Mutex<collections::string::String>>`, which is non-copyable
src/main.rs:102     let receive_loop = thread::spawn(move || {
src/main.rs:103         
src/main.rs:104       
src/main.rs:105         // Receive loop
src/main.rs:106         for message in receiver.incoming_messages() {
src/main.rs:107             let message: Message = match message {
                ...
src/main.rs:102:35: 153:3 help: perhaps you meant to use `clone()`?
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I still can't access `globaltest` in another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a problem, you should spend time reducing the problem. This helps you understand where the problem is and is likely to remove extraneous details that may be confusing you.

In this case, you could start by removing all of the other `match` arms, replacing them with `panic!` calls. Then try replacing libraries with your own code, then eventually just standard library code. Eventually you will get to something much smaller that reproduces the problem.

This is called [creating an MCVE](/help/mcve), and is highly encouraged when you ask a question on Stack Overflow. However, it's 100% useful to yourself whenever you have a problem you don't yet understand. As a professional programmer, you are expected to do this legwork.

Here's one possible MCVE I was able to create:

```
use std::{str, thread};

fn main() {
    let mut global_string = "one";

    let child = thread::spawn(move || {
        let payload = b"Some allocated raw data".to_vec();
        let s = str::from_utf8(&payload).unwrap();
        global_string = s;
    });

    println!("{}", global_string);
}
```

And it produces the same error ("reference must be valid for the static lifetime"). Specifically, the `global_string` variable is a `&'static str`, while `s` is a `&str` with a lifetime equivalent to the `payload` it is borrowed from. Simply put, the `payload` will be deallocated before the thread exits, which means that the string would point to invalid memory, which could cause a crash or security vulnerability. This is a class of errors that Rust prevents against.

This is what [fjh is telling you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35323796/155423).

Instead, you need to be able to ensure that the string will continue to live outside of the thread. The simplest way is to allocate memory that it will control. In Rust, this is a `String`:

```
use std::{str, thread};

fn main() {
    let mut global_string = "one".to_string();

    let child = thread::spawn(move || {
        let payload = b"Some allocated raw data".to_vec();
        let s = str::from_utf8(&payload).unwrap();
        global_string = s.to_string();
    });

    println!("{}", global_string);
}
```

Now we've changed the error to "use of moved value: `global_string`", because we are transferring ownership of the `String` from `main` to the thread. We could try to fix that by cloning the string before we give it to the thread, but then we wouldn't be changing the outer one that we want.

Even if we could set the value in the outer thread, we'd get in trouble because we'd be creating a race condition where two threads are acting in parallel on one piece of data. You have no idea what state the variable is in when you try to access it. That's where a `Mutex` comes in. It makes it so that multiple threads can safely share access to one piece of data, one at a time.

However, you still have the problem that only one thread can own the `Mutex` at a time, but you need two threads to own it. That's where `Arc` comes in. An `Arc` can be cloned and the clone can be given to another thread. Both `Arc`s then point to the same value and ensure it is cleaned up when nothing is using it any more.

Note that we have to clone the `Arc<Mutex<String>>>` *before* we spawn the thread because we are transferring ownership of it into the thread:

```
use std::{str, thread};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let global_string = Arc::new(Mutex::new("one".to_string()));
    let inner = global_string.clone();

    let child = thread::spawn(move || {
        let payload = b"Some allocated raw data".to_vec();
        let s = str::from_utf8(&payload).unwrap();
        *inner.lock().unwrap() = s.to_string();
    });

    child.join().unwrap();

    let s = global_string.lock().unwrap();
    println!("{}", *s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks your detailed answer!, very clear and easy to understand!

Answer (score 5):

> When I remove `globaltest = s`, the code builds and runs without problems.

Yes, because that assignment is not safe to do. You're trying to modify a local variable declared in the main thread from within your other thread. That could lead to all sorts of problems, like data races, which is why the compiler won't let you do it.

It's difficult to say what the best way to fix this is without knowing more about what you want to do. That being said, you could probably fix this by making `globaltest` an `Arc<Mutex<String>>` instead of a `&str`, so you could safely access it from both threads.